# Removing a node

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to remove a span tag inside a label tag after a button is clicked. I thought i cold use an if statement, but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe my syntax is wrong. Any help would be awesome. here is my JavaScript:

```
 validate : function(){
 var span = document.createElement('span');
 var txt = document.createTextNode('*Required Field');
 span.appendChild(txt);
 var check = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var lbl = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
 var len = check.length;

if(lbl.nodeType === span){lbl.removeNode(span)};

for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
     if (check[i].value ==='')
     {  
          span = document.createElement('span');
          txt = document.createTextNode('*Required Field');
          span.appendChild(txt);
          lbl[i].appendChild(span);
        // alert('required');
         // return false;
     }
 };
 return false
  },
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
<ul>
<li><label>First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname" size="30"  /></li>
<li><label>Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname" size="30"  /></li>
<li><label>Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone" size="30"  /></li>
<li><label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email" size="30" /></li>
<li><input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit"  id="submit"/></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">obj.init();</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)... there is no method `removeNode`. You are looking for `removeChild`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild. Also, `lbl.nodeType` returns `undefined` , which can **never** be equal to a DOM node (`span`). `lbl` is a **list of elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can use for your if statement:

```
if (lbl && lbl[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() === "span") {
    lbl[0].parentElement.removeChild(lbl[0])
};
```

Really it should be cleaned up more though. You should probably use `document.getElementById` rather than `document.getElementsByTagName`, for instance.

Comment: this almost works. it keeps deleting "first name", "last Name', "phone", "Email". But i need it to delete the "*required" that appears next to those names when there is a blank field. Itried playing with it, but couldnt get it.

Comment: Oh, well that does make sense, we're deleting lbl, not the span. I didn't fully understand your code before, I was just trying to make that one line work. Now I'm wondering why you create a span above the loop, since it's unused. And why the check to remove isn't inside the loop.